# Can stress be generalised to points?

Tags: solid-mechanics

I know we can talk about a 'stress' in an area for which a 'uniform' force acts, can we generalise this to the stress at each point in the area, by making smaller areas around a point such that:

Over the area $S=\frac{F}{A}$ we can determine that $s=\frac{F}{A_s}$ and then take the limit as $A_s$ approaches $0$ yielding $s=\frac{F}{dA}$ over all of $A$?

Is stress evenly distrubuted across all points such that $S=\frac{F}{A}=\frac{F}{dA}$ so we can talk about stress over infinitesimal areas as well? Even areas under uniform force?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, stress is primarily defined  for a point. Also keep in mind that stress is a vector quantity (not scalar). So the stress, on the same point can be different in different direction.

However, Even in the same cross-section adjacent points can have different stress (even in the same direction). e.g. have a look at the stress distribution of the following tensile specimen.

[image]

You can see that even in the same cross section on the curved region the stresses at adjacent points are significantly different. (although in the picture here a Von Mises stress is used, similar patters can be observed for the $\sigma_{xx}, \sigma_{yy}, \sigma_{zz}, \tau_{xy}, \tau_{yz},\tau_{zx}$ )

---

Its just that it is easier and more intuitive for a first year student to explain it in larger crosssection/surfaces, rather than using a 3d infinitesimal cube.

[image]

Comment: Stress is not a vector, it is a tensor

Answer (score 0):

$S = \dfrac{F}{A} = \dfrac{Mc}{I}$. The stress in the latter case is non-uniform but in the form of linear varying.

Is the stress derived from $S = \dfrac{F}{A}$ really uniform? No, depending on the flexibility of the element in contact, and the support rigidity, the true stresses may vary. But for the force applied over a small, limited area, the variation is insignificantly small, thus the average is conveniently taken as a uniform stress over the entire surface area.

Yes, $S = \dfrac{F}{A}$, when $A$ approaches zero, the force goes to infinite, which is considered a point load; whether it is uniform or non-uniform is inconsequential, as the stress variation will be negligibly small.